# Is "...which are tended to be depicted..." correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

It was mentioned that the sentence "***...which are tended to be depicted...***" is grammatically false and should be replaced with "***...which tend to be depicted...***".

Would it be like "*ain't*", in the linguistic sense, where technically it is wrong but linguistically right?

Comment: Define 'technically wrong'. Lots of people say 'ain't' but nobody says 'are tended to be...'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey numbers aside, is it not comparable to ain't ? it is grammatically wrong, no ?

Comment: Whether dialect, casual, or informal forms are 'wrong' is a tricky matter. Are you suggesting that 'are tended to be...' is some kind of dialect?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey no, i wouldn't be able to support such a claim (though it wouldn't be wrong) and yes it is tricky.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey it is used though. ex: "_While in Persian, adjuncts like English are tended to be located initially within a sentence._" https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/EJ1127434.pdf

Comment: All the authors of that paper seem to be Iranians, and are probably not native English speakers. I found some odd formulations just on the first page, e.g.: _There is also the notion of system as, where linguistic systems are considered to furnish the
background for elements of structure_

Comment: @PrimataLógico Yeah, your source is just wrong. "are tended to be" is never used as Michael mentions. You could say "which tended to be depicted" (without the "are"). In that case it would be understandably correct and possibly used, but the meaning is slightly different.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey yeah, i thought it'd be a stretch but they are part of the English department and probably had their studies in English lit. Being native isn't necessarily a sign of being knowledgeable in the language. (Whether it be English or any other language)

Comment: @PrimataLógico being native is a pretty good sign of knowledge of the language, but besides that, the point is, Michael found other "odd" formulations  as well which further indicate, regardless of nationality, that the authors may not have perfect/idiomatic English.

Comment: @EliHarold "_which tended to be depicted_", as u've mentioned, is slightly off (meaning wise). Not being used is one thing but being completely false is another. What i've noticed is that nothing truly captures the intended meaning behind "_are tended to be_"

Comment: @EliHarold yes i agree but again not necessarily. I have seen European nationals correct ppl from the middle-east on their own native languages and vise-versa. Other sources might be found regarding the usage of the phrase (https://lca.sfsu.edu/lcanews/2018/06/05/817923-professor-mcdaniel-discusses-california-primary-san-francisco-elections) but it's usage is not my main issue.

Comment: In the most recent source you mention "candidates that are tended to be perceived to be" is the worst phrase I have even seen on a reasonable website. Regardless of correctness it is very hard to read and again, should not be used. "tended to be perceived to be" should be replaced with "**tend** to be perceived **as**."

Comment: @EliHarold alright then, but if there is no meaning behind it, how were u able to determine that "_the meaning is slightly different_" when you said to replace it with "_which tended to be depicted_"

Comment: @PrimataLógico because that is a reasonable sentence since "are" is not used. In that case "tended" is the past tense (different meaning). In other words: "in the past, it would tend to be depicted" versus the alternative you propose which is "which tend to be depicted" meaning they **currently** are tending to be depicted. "are tended to be" suggest present and past, which is why it is confusing and should not be used.

Comment: @EliHarold I fully understand what you're trying to say but do keep in mind that "_should not be used_" isn't exactly an argument. I could agree that it is "_very hard to read_" but that isn't the question posed. "Correctness" IS. Also many argue (as was argued in the past) that "_ain't_" shouldn't be used !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135016/discussion-between-eli-harold-and-primata-logico).

Comment: `it's usage` - physician, cure thyself!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey lol

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong.

This appears to be a relative clause, in which the word "which" functions as a pronoun and the subject of the verb.

So we can ask if a sentence "(subject) are tended to be depicted (as something) (by someone)" might be correct.

> Dogs are tended to be depicted as happy animals, by the artist.

This passive form would have an active equivalent:

> The artist tends dogs to be depicted as happy animals.

Oh dear.  This is certainly wrong. The meaning of "tend" is intransitive, but here it has a direct object. That is a grammar error.

Thus the passive form, and by implication, the passive form in a relative clause are all *incorrect*.

This is unlike the use of "ain't", which is correct in some registers of English.

There is a transitive verb form "tend (something)" it means "care for (something)".  So "The patient's cut was tended by the nurse" is correct and so  "The cut which is tended by the nurse will heal quickly" would be correct grammar (though not very idiomatic).

Comment: "The artist tends to depict dogs as happy animals" would be the equivalent ! Its passive would be "Dogs are tended to be depicted as happy animals, by the artist".

Comment: That's half right.  "The artist tends to depict dogs as happy animals" is correct.  But this intransitive verb has no passive form.  So "Dogs are tended to be depicted as happy animals, by the artist" is incorrect English.  It is not slang or a casual expression, it is just wrong.